# Wordpress Theme Conflict With Plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have updated the Wordpress to the Latest Version of it as well as the Plugins of my site. and I notice that the I can't transact any order in my site. I seems that the whole functionof Woocommerce is not working properly. can the downgrading of the Woocommerce will fix the issue? What can else can I do except with the Upgrading of the theme it self.

Comment: Because of this kind of cases it is strongly recommended that make backup of your `database` before updating of `wordpress` in both manual or auto update. So that if any trouble you get then you have one option to downgrade wordpress. But in case of plugin, that can be downgrade easily. So you can try that if you feel that might solve the issue.

Comment: @Rishabh will it delete any products I already added?

Comment: Woocommerce products are use to store in database. So I don't think downgrading woocommerce will effect products in any way since they are in database. But still before attempting it, you should try this in `localhost` first! If this successful in local then you can do it in live project.

Comment: I found an article who described well about downgrading woocommerce without loosing data. In the beginning of article installation process is described. Find paragraph with heading `"Revert to a previous version"` or use find option to reach to this paragraph. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installing-uninstalling-woocommerce/

Comment: @Rishabh thanks for the info but I will still try it on the localhost before on the live site.

Comment: @Rishabh after all the testing I have done on the localhost I have finally make it work. I just downgrade the plugin related to it and seems working fine.

Comment: That's great! If you solved your problem this way then don't forget to share your solution by posting your solution as an answer, so that future viewer of this post can get some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the problem with Downgrading the Woocommerce based on the Theme Woocommerce.
The steps would be:

1. Deactivate the Current Woocommerce Plugin
2. Using FTP or File Manager delete the content of the folder "woocommerce"
3. Download the Older Version of Woocommerce
4. Unzip and Upload using FTP
5. Activate again the Plugin